# add hadoop servers to same cluster(Master-Slave )

Tags: hadoop

I have 2 hadoop pseudo(standalone) servers, which I created for testing purposes.
Now I want to club the two servers into one cluster and make this a Master-Slave configuration.
Is there anyway to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**
Determine which pseudo you want to be master. Once decided add master machine name in file

```
$hadoop_home/conf/master
```

**Step 2**

If u want other pseudo as well as master machine to act as DataNodes then add these machine names in file

```
$hadoop_home/conf/slaves
```

**Step 3**

Make SSH password less connection between master and slave. And change

```
/etc/hosts
```

file if necessary if they are getting connected.

**Step 4**
Now prepare the hadoop MultiNode Cluster to start

Format namenode

```
$hadoop_home/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Start the cluster

```
$hadoop_home/bin/start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, just follow [Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)